# How to use VARRAY in where clause of a select query in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I got a trouble in executing a select count (*) query having a where clause. I put codes into a procedure.

I declare three arrays (VARCHAR2):  v_nameTableArray, v_nameColumnArray,  v_valueArray.

And then I assign value to three arrays.

```
v_nameTableArray:= nameTableArray('Dimension_Product', 'Dimension_Store', 'Dimension_Customer','Dimension_Supplier');

v_nameColumnArray:= nameColumnArray('PRODUCT_ID', 'STORE_ID', 'CUSTOMER_ID','SUPPLIER_ID');

v_valueArray:= valueArray('1', '2', '3','4');
```

My aim is checking exists these values in each table corresponding to name of columns. When I try to run Procedure, I got errors:

```
•   Error(19,4): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 
•   Error(21,39): PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
```

Sentence error is:

```
when exists(select count(*) from v_nameTableArray(i) where  v_nameColumnArray(i) = v_valueArray(i)).
```

Can I anyone guide me how to fix issue? Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CallArray1
IS
  type nameTableArray IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(10);
  v_nameTableArray nameTableArray;

  type nameColumnArray IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(10);
  v_nameColumnArray  nameColumnArray; 

  type valueArray IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(10);
  v_valueArray  valueArray;

  v_checkExists NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
 v_nameTableArray:= nameTableArray('Dimension_Product', 'Dimension_Store', 'Dimension_Customer','Dimension_Supplier');
  v_nameColumnArray:= nameColumnArray('PRODUCT_ID', 'STORE_ID', 'CUSTOMER_ID','SUPPLIER_ID');
  v_valueArray:= valueArray('1', '2', '3','4');

    FOR i in 1 .. v_nameTableArray.count LOOP
            select 
                case 
                    when exists(select count(*) from v_nameTableArray(i) where  v_nameColumnArray(i) = v_valueArray(i))
                    then 1  -- yes
                    else 0  -- no
                end into v_checkExists
            from DUAL;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('---------------' || v_checkExists );

     if v_checkExists = 1 then
        update ….
     else
        insert into…
     end if;
  END LOOP; 
END;
```